# Instagram profile image is blurred

Tags: adobe-photoshop, images, image-editing, blur

When I upload this 110x110px image with 100px resolution it seams blurry.

[image]

Have any idea what's happening? Do you think it's the color?

Answer (score 2):

Cristina!
According to [these guys here](https://codeless.co/instagram-profile-picture-size/), upload an image that is 180x180. This might have changed due to the last adjustments to keep up with density pixel in the available screens.

It also includes point by point pixel sizes for different types of publications. 
I hope it works

Answer (score 1):

Your base image is low resolution to begin with, and was at some point anti-aliased whilst at a small scale - leading to a blurry image by definition.

And to be clear - if the image is 110 x 110 pixels, what do you mean when you say 100 px resolution?

Do you mean it's being resampled on-the-fly by Instagram's own HTML based image manipulation systems to be forced to 100 x 100, because if so, that will ***definitely*** result in anti-aliasing issues with a circular edge of that scale.

If you are the author of the image, and have the original (vector I presume) file, I'd say export to exactly the resolution (pixel count) needed for the given usage, to keep more control of the quality of the output - the moment you allow someone else's logic to apply to resampling your image, you have ceded control of image quality to them.

That said, at the design level, given a target resolution of 100 x 100 with a circular edge profile, you're guaranteed to have issues, as the resolution is just ***so*** *low* that there's *no way* that curve ***can*** be rendered without anti-aliasing or jagged aliased edges, and anti-aliasing by its nature introduces some "blurriness" to your image even without resampling. The wider the stroke of that circle profile, the less obvious this effect will be, BTW.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this list](https://www.godaddy.com/garage/facebook-profile-picture-size-and-more/) of image sizes for social media profile images, 110px square is the smallest image you can provide. Think of it like an image in photoshop, if it starts out small, when you scale it up it will look blurry. Try saving out the image at 1080px squared. That will provide much more information in the image to scale it into the frame on your profile.

I've been working in web for seven years, this is true for all sites were you upload a profile image. It's going to be transmitted and treated, give them a nice big image to play with as it will be compressed for storage on their servers too.